# Turning off Alert When Button Is Pressed Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have alert view using this code:

```
func alert() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Time Is Up",
                                  message: "Either your company has Sold or had to Fold! (Click the button below to see)",
                                  preferredStyle: .alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Next", style: .default) { _ in
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "congratsSegue", sender: nil)
    }

    alert.addAction(action)

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I want to then turn this alert off when the done button pressed:

```
@IBAction func donePressed() {
}
```

Is this possible to do in Swift?

Comment: you can also add 2 action buttons on UIAlert one for next and one cancel.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I don't think you would want to do that, but you could I suppose. `self` here is the viewController.

Comment: You can not dismiss alert on button click because when alert is present on view controller you don't have access of view controller.for best option is you need to set one more action like cancel and on click you can dismiss alert.

Comment: Actually this does not work. Yeah @Donal I would do that but it is quiz so once the time is up I want them to go to next controller. Any work around?

Comment: Just make your own presentation UI with it's own hide and display methods. Should be pretty easy and I'm sure there are tons of libraries on GitHub.

Comment: @Josh you mean when time is up for quiz alert should automatically dismiss and go to next controller or you need to set ant action on button.